# PHP mysql matching multiple row results

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is there a faster way to get database results from rows that match a series of numbers?

For example, I have this...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scores WHERE p_cat=10 OR p_cat=11 OR p_cat=12 OR p_cat=13 OR p_cat=14 OR p_cat=15 OR p_cat=16 OR p_cat=17 OR p_cat=18 OR p_cat=19 ORDER BY p_time ASC LIMIT 50")
```

so basically I'd like it to match row that match any number 10 through 19.  But all of these ORs seem so redundant and daunting... especially when I have to do this for ranges of tens up to 200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `BETWEEN`:

```
WHERE p_cat BETWEEN 10 AND 19
```

If it's not a consecutive sequence, use `IN`:

```
WHERE p_cat IN (10, 12, 13, 15, 19)
```

Comment: is that actually any faster?  Or just more concise?

Comment: I think it's likely to be faster, especially if there's an index on the column.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to fetch the desired result
 WHERE p_cat BETWEEN 10 AND 1

```
           $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scores
               WHERE p_cat>=10 AND p_cat<=19   
              ORDER BY p_time ASC LIMIT 50")
```